# How to retrieve camera metadata via Qt on android

Tags: android, qt, qml, qt5

I am trying to read metadata about the camera settings while an image is taken via Qt's QCamera/QML Camera interface.
Retrieving the image data is no problem at all but I cannot get any metadata at all.

The QML Camera's metadata group is emtpy. The associated `mediaObject` gives an empty list when calling `QMediaObject::metaData()` and `QMedaObject::isMetaDataAvailable()` returns `false`.

How can I retrieve metadata for the camera on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only multimedia plugin that implements reading metadata (as of Qt 5.11) is qnx as it is the only plugin that implements the QMetaDataReaderControl interface. This is used by QMediaObject to retrieve metadata.

I believe we would need an implementation of `QMetaDataReaderControl` for Android to get camera metadata.

PS: There already is a `AndroidMediaMetadataRetriever` that queries "android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever" via JNI to retrieve metadata from files but not from the camera.

PPS: To retrieve metadata from the camera, Qt would have to implement a new connector for the android.hardware.camera2 package. There is a [request for this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55614) but it is of low priority until the deprecated android.hardware.camera package is removed.